# sIFR 3 Leading and Kerning

Tags: javascript, sifr

I am trying to get leading and kerning to work on some sIFR 3 type on a site I'm working on (as described in the wiki: http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Styling), but these two parameters seem to have no effect no matter what I do.

I am not using intergers (no 'px' or 'em') just as it requires.  I've also tried several different font swf files, just to make sure it's not the font.  I don't know why it doesn't work.  All of the other css parameters that I assign to .sIFR-root work just fine.  Here's a sample of my code using 'leading'.

In sifr_config.js:

```
sIFR.replace(snl, {
    selector: '.section-title h1',
    css: ['.sIFR-root { color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; leading:2; }'],
    wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

In the HTML doc:

```
<div class="section-title">
    <h1>sIFR Text</h1>
</div>
```

(I've also tried the css code with and without the square brackets, as I've seen it done both ways.  Doesn't seem to make a difference).

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO Kerri. I have no idea what could be wrong (The code looks fine) but can you add the relevant HTML code around the actual `<h1>` for completeness?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Pekka!  I've added the html code.  Though, as I mentioned, all of the other parameters (font, color, text-align, etc. work).  Only leading and tracking don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ETA: Found an less hackish way:
line-height seems to work when added to the CSS for the replaced element (in my example that'd be: .sIFR-active .section-title h1).  So I was able to use regular old line-height to fake a margin.

---

All righty—since this one left everyone speechless, here's what I discovered:

Originally, there were many suggestions for using leading as a replacment for margin-top or padding-top since these will not work with sIFR.  This is what I was trying to use it for.  I had a single line of text and needed to give it some space up top, so I was trying to do this by increasing the leading (line height) to no avail. I think this worked at one point, but then as I was looking at the change logs for all the revisions of sIFR, I found a note about a "fix" to leading.  Apparently the developer considered leading being recognized on single-line text as a bug, so "fixed" it so that leading is only applied when the text is multiple lines.  I tested by putting a line-break before my text, and sure enough, leading started to work!

So it seems that now, in order to achieve a top margin on my sIFR header, I have to add unneccessary code one way or another—by wrapping it in a div or span with a top margin, or by adding a line break and using negative leading.

I still have no idea about the kerning, but letter-spacing seems to be working, so…

If anyone has any additional insight to offer, I'm all ears!

Comment: You can use `offsetTop` to move the text down, and `tuneHeight` to make the Flash movie taller so the text won't get cut off at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! I'd actually tried that, but for some reason I couldn't get tuneHeight to work as I needed.  I actually ended up doing it in a different way that was a lot less hackish than what I posted above.  I was able to apply line-height to the .sIFR-active replaced class, and that seemed to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me, using sIFR 3 to get a h2 with Serifa font in red with minimal letter spacing and leading. The actual sIFR swf is nothing special, simply created as per the sIFR documentation. As mentioned above, offsetTop and tuneHeight also work for adjusting positioning (shown below although I haven't used them so set to 0).

In sifr.css

```
.sIFR-active h2.replace {
    color: #FF0000;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
```

in sifr-config.js

```
sIFR.replace(serifa, {
    selector: 'h2.replace',
    css: ['.sIFR-root { letter-spacing: -2; leading: -15; kerning:true; color:#FF0000; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:2.5em; }' ], 
    tuneWidth: '0' , tuneHeight: '0' , offsetTop: '0' });
```

In html page (for example):

```
<div class="column grid_4">
    <h2 class="replace">Title here</h2>
</div>
```